# Visual Studio 2010 C# Comment/Documentation Generator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, documentation-generation, xml-documentation, visual-studio-extensions

Does anyone know of a Visual Studio 2010 C# plugin that will:

1. allow me to easily modify (or create a new) xml Comment Template. I need to add
   a few user specific tags to the template. For example, when I'm commenting a method
   I would like the tag  automatically inserted, along
   with Summary and Param when I type ///.
2. allow me to modify the html style template that is used when extracting the comments
   into a nice looking html document. I'd like the documentation added via 1) above to show
   up in the HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) to create/update your documentation (as comments within your code), and then pass it though [Sandcastle](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) (for XML-doc comment format) or [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) (for XML, JavaDoc or Qt comment formats) to generate external html (etc) documentation.

(Note: I'm the author of Atomineer Pro Documentation. See also GhostDoc, VSDocMan, DocumentX for other systems that may also suit your needs)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many tools for this job and [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) is the greatest tool I've ever seen. It has a free and paid version.

Comment: I don't think Ghostdoc generates the pretty HTML output file containing the comments ??? or does it ?

Comment: for the second purpose I always use [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com) in which you can build CHM and HTML documentation and even MSDN like documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try our [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html). This is a commercial application and it can do both 1. and 2.